# How to format a modeless dialog

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a modeless dialog box that displays the contents of a row of cells.
However the data is all run together, celldata, celldata, celldata, celldata.

I've found very little info about formatting a modeless dialog, and what examples I have found contain only some text or a yes/no question to answer.
Formatting a width/height is easy enough but doesn't do what I need.

I'm not finding anything about how to format that so that it is laid out VERTICALLY like this:
celldata
celldata
celldata
celldata

Can anyone offer a push?

Comment: Construct an HTML string from the data. Odds are your data is in an array, so use standard JavaScript to access its elements and format them as you desire

Comment: This would be basic css/html. Add line break `</br>` or  construct a table with `<table>`,`<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

Comment: You can build the HTML on the server in a GS file or construct the HTML on the client side in the browser.  There are multiple ways you could do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating a custom dialog and placing the values of a row vertically.  In this case the 1st row of the spreadsheet is a name for the column values.  This example demonstrates the use of HTMLTemplate, and google.script.run to request data from the spreadsheet.  There are 4 files, Code.gs, HTML_Table.html, JS_Table.html and CSS_Table.html.

Code.gs

```
function test() {
  try {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Table").evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, "Table");
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function initTable() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var table = {};
  table.rowCount = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
  table.values = sheet.getRange(1,1,2,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();  // 2 rows
  return JSON.stringify(table);
}

function getRow(i) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var row = {};
  row.values = sheet.getRange(i,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];  // only 1 row
  return JSON.stringify(row);
}
```

HTML_Table.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('CSS_Table'); ?>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="selectRow" onchange="getRow()">
    </select>
    <div id="tableRows">
    </div>
    <?!= include('JS_Table'); ?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS_Table.html

```
<style>
  td { border-style: solid }
</style>
```

JS_Table.html

```
<script>
  (function () {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
      function (value) {
        var rows = JSON.parse(value);
        var select = document.getElementById("selectRow");
        for( var i=1; i<=rows.rowCount; i++ ) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = i;
          select.add(option);
        }
        var div = document.getElementById("tableRows");
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute("id","tableCells");
        for( var i=0; i<rows.values[0].length; i++ ) {
          var row = document.createElement("tr");
          var cell = document.createElement("td");
          cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rows.values[0][i]));
          row.appendChild(cell);
          cell = document.createElement("td");
          cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rows.values[1][i]));
          row.appendChild(cell);
          table.appendChild(row);
        }
        div.appendChild(table);
      }
    ).initTable();
  }());

  function getRow() {
    var row = document.getElementById("selectRow").selectedIndex+1;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
      function (value) {
        var row = JSON.parse(value);
        var table = document.getElementById("tableCells");
        for( var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++ ) {
          table.rows[i].cells.item(1).innerHTML = row.values[i];
        }
      }
    )
    .getRow(row);
  }
</script>
```